# Jquery datepicker - format date to dd/mm/yy

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have been trying to change our datepicker 
from:  mm/dd/yyyy (jquery mm/dd/yy) 
to:  dd/mm/yyyy  (jquery dd/mm/yy).

First I tried using *parseDate* to no affect, then we tried *formatDate*

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?
Note: we are using a jquery ui frame work

```
 $(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();

 });
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat' , 'dd/mm/yy');
```

Comment: Thank you very much however it should be 'dd/mm/yy'

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `dateFormat` option:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```